# How to pull a access section of an automatically generated connection string in Web.Config

Tags: c#, web-config, connection-string

I'm building an MVC web application with a small team and am working on code that will allow each of us to have a local test database on our own machine using an EDM as the source framework. I created the model, then each of us will have to "Generate DB from Model" and do the initial database set up for each of our machines.

The roadblock I hit is I can't figure out how to pull the section of the huge Metadata connection string that gets automatically generated and stored in `Web.config` I need to set up the `SQLConnection` for our queries

Basically I want to take this massive string that gets returned by `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[dbName].ConnectionString;`:

```
    connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.TestDataModels.LocalTestData.csdl|res://*/Models.TestDataModels.LocalTestData.ssdl|res://*/Models.TestDataModels.LocalTestData.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-SHUF4P9\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=myLocalTestDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
```

and access only this portion of it:

```
connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-SHUF4P9\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=myLocalTestDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quote;
```

Normally I would just hard-code it into a Data.config file, but since this is a Local test DB, the connection string is going to be different for each of us.

Comment: This seems like an X Y problem. Typically a web application uses a central server and one or more centrally located databases. The fact that you are deploying it to multiple clients seems to fit more in line with a thick client application architecture. Not to mention, unless you are using .NET Core you can't even launch your application without installing IIS.

Comment: Use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396